# Junit Test case for applicationContext.getBean(class) returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

When trying to write test case for applicationContext.getBean(classname). Getting null pointer exception.
Below is the Java class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyClassName {

  @Autowired
  ServiceOne serviceOne;

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;


  public getCitizenData(String mobileNumber) {

    CitizenDataService citizenDataService = applicationContext.getBean(CitizenDataService.class, mobileNumber);
    log.info("Getting Data");
    return citizenDataService.searchMethod(mobileNumber)
         // While debugging test file citizenDataService is coming as Null Hence getting Null Pointer exception
        .flatMap(.............
         )
```

Test File

```
class MyClassNameTest {

  private MyClassName mockMyClassName;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mockMyClassName = new MyClassName();
    mockMyClassName.serviceOne = mock(ServiceOne.class);
    mockMyClassName.applicationContext = mock(ApplicationContext.class);
    //mockMyClassName.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
  }

  @Test
  void testGetCitizenData() {
    // Setup
    // Configure ApplicationContext.getBean(...).
    final CitizenDataService citizenDataService = new CitizenDataService("mobileNumber");
    when(mockMyClassName.applicationContext.getBean(CitizenDataService.class, "args"))
        .thenReturn(citizenDataService);

    final result = mockMyClassName.getCitizenData("mobileNumber");
    // While debugging this citizenDataService is coming as Null Hence getting Null Pointer exception
```

How to write test case for this ?

Comment: Your behavior doesn't match thus it returns `null`. You are matching against `args` while you put in `mobileNumber`. Doesn't match, default behavior return `null`. Hence `NullPointerException`. Next you have no behavior for the `searchMethod`, again default behavior `null` again a `NullPointerException`. So even if you fix the first, you will get a `NullPointerException` again but a line later.

Comment: yes @M.Deinum correctly pointed. At later also i am getting Null Pointer

Answer (score 0):

It is because you stub the incorrect arguments on the `getBean()` on the mocked `ApplicationContext` . When a method on a mock is called but there are no matching stubbed arguments , it will return either null or an empty collection , or 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean by default . So in you case NULL `CitizenDataService` is returned.

Changing the following should fix your problem :

```java
 when(mockMyClassName.applicationContext.getBean(CitizenDataService.class, "mobileNumber"))
    .thenReturn(citizenDataService);
```

Another way is not to mock the `ApplicationContext` but use spring test to really start up the spring container which include the beans there are required for the test case :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyClassName.class,ServiceOne.class,CitizenDataService.class})
public class MyClassNameTest {

     @Autowired
     private MyClassName myClassName
  

      @Test
      void testGetCitizenData() { 

     }

}
```

This will be slower than the plain Mockito approach because it needs more time to start up the spring container and also require you to manage what beans to be included in the context.

For me , I would refactor your class such that it does not require to autowire `ApplicationContext` into it and then write a plain Mockito test. It is not a good practise to get the bean from the `ApplicationContext` manually which will make your class coupled to the spring framework codes.

Comment: thanks @KenChan for help but using both as mentioned above is throwing the same Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend mocking the application context. There are simply too many methods with similar arguments that it is difficult to mock the correct ones. Instead, use one of the readily available implementations written specifically for the use in tests, such as [`StaticApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/StaticApplicationContext.html).

```
class MyClassNameTest {
  private MyClassName mockMyClassName;
  private ApplicationContext appCtx;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mockMyClassName = new MyClassName();
    mockMyClassName.serviceOne = mock(ServiceOne.class);
    this.appCtx = new StaticApplicationContext();
  }

  @Test
  void testGetCitizenData() {
    appctx.registerBean(CitizenDataService.class, () -> new CitizenDataService("mobileNumber"));

    final result = mockMyClassName.getCitizenData("mobileNumber");
```